Clang-format splitting method calls and statements on multiple lines
I am using clang-format version 18 on windows.
In  most cases, we would like all the arguments in method calls to be on the same line, but in complex cases, we want them on separate lines and aligned. The problem is that clang-format bases "complex" on the line length. We would like to be able to split the line based upon the number of arguments. If the method call has 5 parameters (for example), we would like them split on separate lines, even if the line length wouldn't be exceeded if they were on one line. but methods with two arguments would put them all on the same line.
We have the same situation with compound statements. we would like statements like
a = b || c || d || e;
to be on separate lines based upon how complex they are, rather than the line length.
I'm not sure this is currently possible with clang-format, but maybe I missed something.
If it isn't possible, can someone point me to some kind of forum for making enhancement requests for clang-format? Thanks
Edit:
I tried setting the columnLimit to 0. The documentation says "A column limit of 0 means that there is no column limit. In this case, clang-format will respect the input’s line breaking decisions within statements unless they contradict other rules.". Those two sentences contradict each other.
Setting the column limit to 0 causes this set of lines:
  bool result = jobControls->AnyOutputFilesPresent(m_panelExcitations) ||
                jobControls->AnyOutputFilesPresent(m_saGraphs) ||
                jobControls->AnyOutputFilesPresent(m_audioSignals);

To be changed to this one line
  bool result = jobControls->AnyOutputFilesPresent(m_panelExcitations) || jobControls->AnyOutputFilesPresent(m_saGraphs) || jobControls->AnyOutputFilesPresent(m_audioSignals);

Here is my config file:
#
#Standard options
#
BasedOnStyle: Google
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Always
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentWidth: 2
Language: Cpp
LineEnding: LF
PointerAlignment: Left
QualifierAlignment: Left
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
#SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 3
SpacesInAngles: Never
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInParens: Never
UseTab: Never

#
# Bracing options
#
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: false
  AfterClass: false
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterStruct: false
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile: true
  IndentBraces: false
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false

#
# spacing options
#
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon : false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: Custom
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false

#
# Indentation options
#
AlignOperands: DontAlign
#AlignOperands: Align
#AlignArrayOfStructures: Right
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
#AlignAfterOpenBracket: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
NamespaceIndentation: All

#
# Line breaking/packing/wrapping options
#
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: InlineOnly
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine : Empty
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: No
PackConstructorInitializers: Never
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: true
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Never
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
ColumnLimit: 0
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave

#
# comment options
#
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Leave
#  Kind: Always
#  OverEmptyLines: 3
ReflowComments: false

AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
RemoveSemicolon: true
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 3
KeepEmptyLinesAtEOF: false

#PenaltyExcessCharacter: 10
#PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 10000
#PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 5000
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 20000

IncludeBlocks: Regroup
SortIncludes: CaseSensitive
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^<Q.*$'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    3
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^<.*$'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    2
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex: '".*"'
    Priority: 4
    SortPriority: 4


Luckily clang-format is very configurable. Just create a .clang-format file in the root of your repository and configure it to your liking. See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

"If it isn't possible, can someone point me to some kind of forum for making enhancement requests for clang-format?" - You can always engage with the developers of clang-format and discuss options and submit your own patches - it's open-source; nothing is stopping you.

clang-format configurator might help (isn't up to 19 yet, it's most recent support is for 18.1.3).

Thanks for the comments, but I'm already playing around with the options in .clang-format and cannot find any that does what I am asking for. I'm also not about to implement enhancements to the tool. I was hoping for a way to submit suggestions so if someone else likes the idea, they could implement it if they like.

Another possibility that someone suggested at my end is that if I could tell the tool not to collapse lines to fit in the maximum line length. Split if the line is too long, but never collapse, but I can't find an option to do that either.

It turns out that BinPackArguments:false conflicts with ColumnLimit: 0. This strikes me as being a bug.
BinPackArguments:false means put all function call arguments on one line or all on separate lines.
ColumnLimit: 0 means don't shift based upon column position.
There are no function call arguments in play here. The lines should not be realigned.
In addition, even if BinPackArguments:false should affect the lines, leaving the lines alone would satisfy both settings.
Setting BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: true also causes the behavior that I am seeing.
Another example is the tool is changing the following lines
  if (ProxyParseTupleAndKeywords(args,
                                 kwds,
                                 "|b:SpecFindContributionCalc.queueAll",
                                 const_cast<char**>(kwlist),
                                 &queueMissingOnly)) {

to
  if (ProxyParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "|b:SpecFindContributionCalc.queueAll", const_cast<char**>(kwlist), &queueMissingOnly)) {

when ColumnLimit: 0 and AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
but it leaves the line unchanged if I comment out AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine even though AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine should not affect that line.
